# Plotting many points on the figure with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot many points on a figure. The method I use is:

```
main_ax.plot(10, 20, '.w')
```

This code can help me polt a point at (10, 20)

But I need to plot many points:

```
data = [(13, 45), (13, 46), (13, 47), (13, 48), (13, 49), (13, 50), (13, 51), (13, 52), (13, 53), (13, 54), (14, 40), (14, 41), (14, 42), (14, 43), (14, 44), (14, 55), (14, 56), (14, 57), (14, 58), (14, 59), (15, 37), (15, 38), (15, 39), (15, 60), (15, 61), (15, 62), (16, 35)]
```

The only way that I know to plot these points is:

```
main_ax.plot(13, 45, '.w')
main_ax.plot(13, 46, '.w')
main_ax.plot(13, 47, '.w')
main_ax.plot(13, 48, '.w')........
```

Is there any other faster method that I can plot many points?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your data into two lists of `x` and `y` coordinates and do a scatter plot:

```
x, y = zip(*data)
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: As an alternative, you can also use `plt.plot(x, y, 'o')`